# Loop through unknown size pointers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am pretty new to Objective C and I am developing a plugin for Osirix.
 In this plugin I need to get all pixels inside each ROI of the series.
The function which gives me the pixels inside the ROI returns a pointer of floats (float *).

My question is: how can I iterate through all values inside this pointer if I don't know and I don't have access to its dimensions ?

I've created the following code to exemplify my question:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        long textHeight = 10;
        long textWidth = 13;

        float *pointer = nil;
        //Pretend that I don't know the dimensions of the pointer.
        pointer = (float *) malloc(textHeight * textWidth * sizeof(float));

        //If the pointer is builded like that, but I don't know it's dimesensions
        long cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < textHeight; i ++){
            for (int j = 0; j < textWidth; j ++){
                pointer[cont] = i * j;

                cont += 1;
            }
        }

        //Code to iterate through all values of the pointer...
        //...
        //...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I edited my question to show more information about the problem. The method that I am calling is the getROIValue (following method) and it is returning a pointer with all values that I need to make some calculations.
Is there a way to parse all the values inside "values"

This is the way I call the method:

```
long noOfValues;
float *pixelsInsideRoi;

pixelsInsideRoi = [pt1pix getROIValue: &noOfValues :roi :0L];
```

-

```
- (float*) getROIValue: (long*)numberOfValues : (ROI*)roi : (float**)locations
{
long            count = 0, no;
float           *values = nil;
long            upleftx, uplefty, downrightx, downrighty;
NSPoint         *pts;

if( roi.type == tPlain)
{
    long            textWidth = roi.textureWidth;
    long            textHeight = roi.textureHeight;
    long            textureUpLeftCornerX = roi.textureUpLeftCornerX;
    long            textureUpLeftCornerY = roi.textureUpLeftCornerY;
    unsigned char   *buf = roi.textureBuffer;

    values = (float*) malloc( textHeight*textWidth* sizeof(float));

    if( locations) *locations = (float*) malloc( textHeight*textWidth*2* sizeof(float));

    if( values) {
        count = 0;

        for( long y = 0; y < textHeight; y++)
        {
            for( long x = 0; x < textWidth; x++)
            {
                if( buf [ x + y * textWidth] != 0)
                {

                    long    xx = (x + textureUpLeftCornerX);
                    long    yy = (y + textureUpLeftCornerY);

                    if( xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height)
                    {

                        float   *curPix = &fImage[ (yy * width) + xx];
                        values[ count] = *curPix;   //fImage[ width*y + x];

                        if( locations)
                        {
                            if( *locations)
                            {
                                (*locations)[ count*2] = xx;
                                (*locations)[ count*2 + 1] = yy;
                            }
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSMutableArray  *ptsTemp = [roi splinePoints];

    if( [ptsTemp count] == 0) return nil;

    [self CheckLoad];

    pts = (NSPoint*) malloc( [ptsTemp count] * sizeof(NSPoint));
    no = [ptsTemp count];
    for( long i = 0; i < no; i++) pts[ i] = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex: i] point];

    upleftx = downrightx = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:0] x];
    uplefty = downrighty = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:0] y];

    for( long i = 0; i < [ptsTemp count]; i++)
    {
        if( upleftx > [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] x]) upleftx = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] x];
        if( uplefty > [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] y]) uplefty = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] y];

        if( downrightx < [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] x]) downrightx = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] x];
        if( downrighty < [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] y]) downrighty = [[ptsTemp objectAtIndex:i] y];
    }

    if( upleftx < 0) upleftx = 0;
    if( downrightx < 0) downrightx = 0;
    if( upleftx > width) upleftx = width;
    if( downrightx > width) downrightx = width;

    if( uplefty < 0) uplefty = 0;
    if( downrighty < 0) downrighty = 0;
    if( uplefty > height) uplefty = height;
    if( downrighty > height) downrighty = height;

    count = 0;
    long y = (downrighty - uplefty);
    long x = (downrightx - upleftx);
    values = (float*) malloc( x*y* sizeof(float));
    if( locations) *locations = (float*) malloc( x*y*2* sizeof(float));

    if( values) {

        for( y = uplefty; y < downrighty ; y++)
        {
            for( x = upleftx; x < downrightx ; x++)
            {

                if( pnpoly( pts, no, x, y) > 0)
                {
                    if( isRGB)
                    {
                        unsigned char*  rgbPtr = (unsigned char*) fImage;
                        long            pos;

                        pos =  4*width*y;
                        pos += 4*x;

                        values[ count] = (rgbPtr[ pos+1] + rgbPtr[ pos+2] + rgbPtr[ pos+3])/3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        values[ count] = fImage[ width*y + x];
                    }

                    if( locations)
                    {
                        if( *locations) {
                            (*locations)[ count*2] = x;
                            (*locations)[ count*2 + 1] = y;
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    y = (downrighty - uplefty);
    x = (downrightx - upleftx);

//      if( count > x*y) NSLog(@"%d / %d", count, (long) ((downrighty - uplefty) * (downrightx - upleftx)));

    if( roi) free( pts);
}

*numberOfValues = count;

return values;
}
```

Comment: if you don't know the structure... than you can't.

Comment: If all you have is `type*`, you only know that the elements are of type `type`.  You have no info on whether it's one element or a million of them (or maybe even a zero-length array).  (This is standard C stuff that you should know before you attempt to use Objective-C.)

Comment: If "standard C stuff" is a pre-resiquite then there go most of the question here. ;-)

Comment: @HotLicks I've modified my question with the real method that is returning the pointer. I don't know if it make the solution easier.

Comment: Do you know the size and/or format of each entry? If so you should be able to work your way through.

Comment: @zaph I called the method this way:                                                                    long noOfValues;                                                                                          float *pixelsInsideRoi = [pt1pix getROIValue: &noOfValues :roi :0L];

Comment: I think I just realized the solution!! I can access the number of data with the pointer (noOfValues).   --->*numberOfValues = count;  I was so blind!